# `...ByKey()` returns null in Kotlin flatbuffers impl

Tags: java, android, kotlin, flatbuffers

I have the following schema:

```
...
table FiltersByDomain {
  domain: string (key);
  filters: [FilterIsIncluded] (required);
}

table Index {
  ...
  filters_by_domain: [FiltersByDomain];
   ...
}

root_type Index;
```

When i use the getter by index and collect the keys i'm able to find some value:

```
        val domains = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
        for (i in 0 until index.filtersByDomainLength) {
            val pair = index.filtersByDomain(i)!!
            domains[pair.domain!!] = pair.filtersLength
        }
        assertTrue(domains.keys.contains("scifinow.co.uk"))
        val someDomain = "dcw50.com"
        assertEquals(3, domains[someDomain]) // succeeds
```

If i use generated `..ByKey` method it returns `null`:

```
        assertEquals(3, index.filtersByDomainByKey(someDomain)!!.filtersLength) // fails
```

Here is the [test](https://gitlab.com/4ntoine/flatbufferskotlin/-/blob/7e15ccc981ea6b1c9af89134d941ff5b7b252b63/lib/src/androidTest/java/com/eyeo/ctu/fb/FlatBuffersLoadTest.kt#L68) (on Android).

PS.
Using `api 'com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:1.12.0'`, the files were generated with `flatc --kotlin -o ../java schema.fbs`

PPS. Just out of curiosity i've tried generated with `flatc --java -o ../java schema.fbs` Java classes and it also fails.

```
> flatc --version
flatc version 1.12.0
```

Comment: Did you make sure `filters_by_domain` is serialized in sorted order? Where is the code that serializes this data?

Comment: @aardappel It's not sorted before serialization (and the code is outside of this repo (but is still under my control)). Does it require to be sorted?

Comment: Yes, it's a binary search.

Comment: It was expected to be sorted during the loading, not saving. Is it documented as a requirement somewhere?

Comment: @Aardappel feel free to convert your comment to answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector that contains the tables needs to be sorted by the `key` field before serialization for lookup with the `ByKey` method to work (it is implemented as a binary search, since FlatBuffers in an in-place zero-copy format, the lookup happens in-place too, instead of constructing a dictionary at the destination).